# Why is '$el.clientWidth' equal to 0 when opening a modal? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I'm trying to get the width of an element that's inside of a modal in my Vue.js website. When the modal opens, the width is 0 when I console.log it, but it's clearly not 0 since the element is visible when the modal opens. The console logs a value > 0 when the modal closes.

Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/chataolauj/pen/RwwYxBg?editors=1010

```
watch: {
    showAdd() {
        console.log(this.$refs.input.$el.clientWidth)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because instantiation of element is after `mounted` this liefcycle and then you could actually get its length.
but the change of `showAdd` is before `mounted`. then you got 0 in fact.

based on your code, you can try this

```
showAdd() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.$refs.input.$el.clientWidth)
  }, 400)
}
```

and it's also influenced by animation factor, this time is about .3s, so `Vue.nextTick` won't work, using `setTimeout(()=>{}, 400)` is also not bad solution unless you listen for animation events.

Comment: That was kind of my assumption of what the issue was. Don't really want to use setTimeout for various reason, but I'll probably have to end up using if I can't find another solution.